# Setting Up Dynamic Sub Domains in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, virtualhost, subdomain

Hello I am currently trying to set up dynamic subdomains picked up from my database on my codeigniter installation whenever i try to access a subdomain i get a 403 error I realize a couple of issues might be causing this I however cannot determin which one it is I am sorry if I am asking an obvious question but i a quite new to this

here is my virtual host set up

```
     <VirtualHost *:80>
         DocumentRoot /var/www
        ServerName www.example.mobi
        ServerAlias example.mobi
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/subs
        ServerName example.mobi
        ServerAlias *.example.mobi
        <Directory /var/www/subs/>
                # Options +Indexes
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Here is my .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    #this is to allow no indexes
    Options All +Indexes

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule> 
AddType image/x-windows-bmp bmp
```

This is the error i see when i try and access a subdomain

```
 [error] [client x.x.s.x] Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /var/www/subs/
```

Additional information would be that i am using this guide
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/basecamp-style-subdomains-with-codeigniter--net-16330

to set up my codeigniter for the subdomains 
*also when i access the domain 
"domain.mobi"
'domain' is echoed as i have set it to echo the subdomain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I since found a solution the subdomain virtual host  just needs to be pointed to the same directory as the main domain and then I can use the subdomain as a parameter

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        **DocumentRoot /var/www**
        ServerName example.mobi
        ServerAlias *.example.mobi
        <Directory /var/www/subs/>
                # Options +Indexes
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```